# On measurability of certain group actions on spaces of bounded measurable functions

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, topological-groups

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a separable Hilbert space equipped with a strongly continuous unitary representation of a locally compact group $G$. Denote by $\mathcal{L}^{\infty}(H)$  the space of the bounded Borel measurable real valued functions on $\mathcal{H}$ (with respect to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of the norm topology) equipped with the sup norm.

Then the representation of $G$ on $\mathcal{H}$ induces, via composition, a representation of $G$ on $\mathcal{L}^{\infty}(H)$. Let $f \in \mathcal{L}^{\infty}(H)$ be fixed and set
$$ \Psi_{f}(g):=g\cdot f, \quad g\in G,  $$
where $\cdot$ stands for the latter representation. Is the map $\Psi_{f}: G \rightarrow \mathcal{L}^{\infty}(H)$ Borel measurable (with respect to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of the sup norm topology) ?

If not, is the function $\ell\circ \Psi_{f}$, where $\ell$ is any (fixed) continuous linear functional on $\mathcal{L}^{\infty}(H)$, measurable?

Any reference would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is Ψ_f(g) an element of L^∞(H)?  The definition you wrote down seems to make it an element of Aut(L^∞(H)).

Comment: Each fixed $f$ gives a map from $G$ to $\mathcal{L}^{\infty}(H)$.

Comment: What σ-algebra of measurable sets is being used for L^∞(H)?

Comment: So to be more explicit, let $\varphi : G \to U(H)$ be the representation.  Then $\Psi_f(g) = f(\varphi(g) \cdot)$, i.e. the function $h \mapsto f(\varphi(g) h)$.  Is that right?

Comment: Dimitri Pavlov, I edited the question to clarify. Nade Eldredge, yes, that's correct.

Comment: This may turn out to be false, since you specifically asked for Borel measurability, and the relevant expression involves projections of Borel sets, which need not be Borel.  However, the map Ψ_f is Lebesgue-measurable, perhaps this is sufficient for your purposes.

Comment: Dimitry Pavlov, I suppose you mean Lebesgue measurable with respect to the completion given by adding the sets of Haar measure zero? Yes, I think that would be good enough for my purposes. But why is the map $\Psi_f$ Lebesgue measurable?

Comment: No. The map $\Psi_f$ is not measurable in any sense. Generally speaking, one should avoid the Borel structure for a non-separable metric space. What is your linear functional $\ell$? Is it somehow explicitly written down in connection with vector in $H$?

Comment: @S.Z.: You may want to use the @ sign to reply to comments (like in this comment), since otherwise no notification will be sent by the system.  The measurability of Ψ_f can be expressed as the measurability of the projection onto G of the set $\{(g,h)\mid α(h)-f(φ(g)(h)) ∈ (a,b)\}$, for all real numbers a<b (with trivial modifications for complex numbers) and a bounded measurable function $α\colon H\to {\bf R}$.  A general criterion for measurability of images under measurable maps (up to a negligible subset) can be found in Proposition 4.59 of the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.05284v2.

Comment: @S.Z.: You can also look into the notion of a perfect measure space, see, for example, 342X(i) in Fremlin's Measure Theory, which shows that maps out of perfect measure spaces have a well-defined point-set image, up to a negligible subset.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov: Thanks a lot, this approach may work but it seems to lead to somewhat involved (at least for me) notion of measurability. Assuming that it works, would the composition of $\Psi_f$ with a functional $\ell$ (see the edited question) be a well-defined element of $L^{\infty}(G)$ (defined with respect to the Haar measure)?

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA:  No, I'm interested in a generic positive continuous linear functional $\ell$.  It looks very plausible to me that $\Psi_f$ is measurable when $f$ is an indicator function of a Borel set. However, due to the non-separability, one may have that only the composition $\ell \circ \Psi_f$ is measurable for a general $f$.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @S.Z.: Consider the characteristic function $\delta_v$ of the one-point subset $\{v\}\subset H$. One has $d(\delta_v,g\cdot\delta_v)=1$ for every $g$ with $gv\neq v$. Hence the range of $\Psi_{\delta_v}$ is discrete and $\Psi_{\delta_v}$ is non-measurable in most of cases.

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA: I agree that uncountable discrete range doesn't look promising in general. Nevertheless I do think the map in question is measurable. The reason is that I have a short argument that derives the measurability from a rather natural property. What would be a good way to attach a file here?

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA: I do not think this example can work as stated, since in L^∞-spaces functions that differ on a set of measure 0 such as {v} must be identified.  So in your example, δ_v = 0.  But perhaps the OP can tell us whether this is actually the case or not.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov: No, $\mathcal{L}^{\infty}(H)$ denotes the bounded measurable functions, without identifications. There are no sets of measure 0 involved in this context.

Comment: In any case, if you want to ignore measure zero (w.r.t. what?) sets, just use a unit ball centered at $v$, instead of the singleton subset $\{v\}$.

Comment: @S.Z.: Since the range is discrete any subset of it is (relatively) open.

Comment: I would suggest to use the ultraweak topology on L^∞ instead of the norm topology.  Is the linear functional $\ell$ continuous in the ultraweak topology?

Comment: @DmitriPavlov: No, I'm interested in general $\ell$.

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA: Here is a link to the file with my argument: https://gofile.io/d/20Gi85.  I think the condition of the lemma is true for  the action of the unitary group of $H$ on $H$. In fact, when $H$ is finite-dimensional, the subsets of $G$ in this condition appear to be finite. So for separable $H$ they are most likely countable.

Comment: @S.Z.: No, it won't work. $\ell\circ\Psi_f$ is not measurable in general. The Borel structure of a non-separable metric space is not generated by balls (as a $\sigma$-algebra), because the topology is not second countable. That's one of many reasons why one should avoid the Borel structure for a non-separable metric space.

Comment: @S.Z.: Perhaps you could provide more context as to why it is crucial not to mod out sets of measure 0 and consider non-ultraweakly-continuous functionals?  What kind of problem imposes such requirements?

Comment: @DmitriPavlov : There are no natural measure 0 sets on $H$ in general. The context of the problem is not that exotic: I'm interested in general finitely additive measures defined on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $H$.To these measures there correspond continuous linear functionals $\ell$. I want to average such functionals (and therefore the corresponding measures) over an invariant mean on $G$, in the case when $G$ is amenable.

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA : I see, so this approach won't work indeed. But may be something else will, after composing with $\ell$. What if we look at $\sigma$-algebra generated by the open balls then? Perhaps a continuous $\ell$ is measurable with respect to that one.

Comment: @S.Z.: A good theory of sets of measure 0 (in particular, you get a σ-ideal invariant under translations) exists for any completely metrizable topological vector space, see the survey by Ott and Yorke "Prevalence", in particular, Definition 3.1 and Proposition 3.3.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov : I looked at your paper and Proposition 4.59 does seem applicable to the projection from $G \times H$ to $G$ ( one may choose, say, a Radon Gaussian probability measure on $H$). However I don't understand the first part of that old comment of yours - why it suffices to establish the measurability of the image of the subsets of $G \times H$ that you describe (and which are indeed measurable) under this projection?

Comment: @S.Z.: It's not sufficient per se, it only establishes that there is a well-defined class of measurable subsets up to a negligible subset that is the image.  Additional work is necessary to deal with the actual set-theoretic image, which is why I mentioned perfect measure spaces in my next comment.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov : Perhaps I didn't state this clearly. The part I don't understand is this:  "The measurability of Ψ_f can be expressed as the measurability of the projection onto G of the set {(g,h)∣α(h)−f(φ(g)(h))∈(a,b)}, for all real numbers a<b (with trivial modifications for complex numbers) and a bounded measurable function α:H→R".  Why is this true?

Comment: @S.Z.: Sorry, I misunderstood what part was meant to be the first.
$Ψ_f$ is Borel measurable if for any open subset of $L^∞$ its preimage is measurable in $G$.
Open subsets of $L^∞$ are (for the norm topology) of the form $\{q ∈ L^∞ \mid ‖p−q‖ < a\}$, for some $p$ and $a$.
The preimage under $Ψ_f$ is then $\{g ∈ G\mid ‖p−gf‖ < a\}$.
The latter set coincides with $\{g ∈ G \mid \forall h∈H\colon p(h)-f(gh) ∈ (-a,a)\}$.
Finally, the last set is the projection onto $G$ of the set $\{(g,h)∈G⨯H\mid p(h)-f(gh) ∈ (-a,a)\}$.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov : Good, but as Narutaka Ozawa noted in one of the comments above, due to the non-separablity, it is not enough to check the measurability of the pre-images of open balls. This looks like a serious obstacle.